# PHP não considera listagem quando tem filtro

Tags: php, jquery-datatables, filtro

Começo da página:

```html
<?php 
include "funcoes.php";
session_start();
$grupo_produto = $_SESSION['grupo_produto'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tabela_produtos').dataTable();
            } );
        </script>
```

Estou fazendo um sistema para realizar pedidos e estou tendo um problema com o dataTable e PHP.
Tenho a listagem de todos os produtos.

Eu pesquiso por um produto e coloco a quantidade desejada, conforme figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai, sem grandes problemas. Eu procuro outro produto, coloco a quantidade e finalizo o pedido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que, ao finalizar o pedido, os únicos produtos que ele coloca no array são os últimos que eu escolhi (nesse caso, os 2 Guaraná Lata).
Ele não considera aquelas Cocas que eu escolhi no começo.

Caso eu faça o pedido sem utilizar o campo pesquisa ou se eu pesquiso, coloco a quantidade e apago o que eu pesquisei (voltando para o formulário com todos os produtos), ele insere normal.

Não vou colocar o código do DataTable aqui pois ele é muito extenso.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar, por favor?
Desde já agradeço.

Código para escolher produto:

```
 <body>
    <form method="post" action="?acao=escolher_produto">
        <table id="tabela_produtos"  >
            <thead>
                <tr>   
                    <td>
                        Cod.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Nome
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Preço
                    </td>
                    <?php 
                    if($grupo_produto == '0'){
                        ?>
                        <td>
                            Preço Broto
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Preço Média
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Preço Giga
                        </td>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <td>
                        Quantidade
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php 
            $array_produtos = mostrarProdutos($grupo_produto);
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                for($i=0; $i< count($array_produtos);$i++){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $array_produtos[$i][0]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $array_produtos[$i][1]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo formataValor($array_produtos[$i][2]); ?>
                        </td>
                        <?php 
                        if($grupo_produto == '0'){
                            ?>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo formataValor($array_produtos[$i][3]);?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo formataValor($array_produtos[$i][4]);?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo formataValor($array_produtos[$i][5]);?>
                            </td>
                        <?php 
                        } 
                        ?>
                        <td> 
                            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais('<?php echo $i;?>')"/> <input type="number" id="<?php echo $i?>" name="<?php echo $i?>" /> 
                            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos('<?php echo $i;?>')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               <?php
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Escolher">
    </form> 
</body>
```

Ação ao clicar em escolher:

```
if(@$_GET['acao'] == 'escolher_produto'){
$array_produtos = mostrarProdutos($_SESSION['grupo_produto']);
if(isset($_SESSION['array_pedido'])){
    $array_pedido = $_SESSION['array_pedido'];    
}else{
    $array_pedido = array();
}
$nenhum_produto = 0;
for($i=0; $i< count($array_produtos);$i++){
    if($_POST[$i] != 0){
        $codigo_produto = $array_produtos[$i][0];
        $descricao = $array_produtos[$i][1];
        $valor_unitario = $array_produtos[$i][2];
        $quantidade = $_POST[$i];
        while($quantidade > 0){
            array_push($array_pedido, array($codigo_produto,$descricao, $valor_unitario));
            $quantidade--;
        }
    }
    $nenhum_produto++;
}
if($nenhum_produto == 0){
    echo "<script> alert('Escolha algum produto'); history.back(); </script>";
}else{

    $_SESSION['array_pedido'] = $array_pedido;
    echo "<script> location.href ='grupo_produtos.php'; </script>";
}
```

}

Comment: Os produtos selecionados ficam na `$_SESSION['array_pedido']`?

Comment: Apenas depois que eu escolho todos os produtos e clico no botão "Escolher", ele armazena nessa $_SESSION['array_pedido'].

Comment: E aonde ficam os produtos escolhidos antes do fechamento do pedido? Está em alguma sessão?

Comment: Não ficam em nenhum lugar. Os produtos só são registrados depois de clicado no botão (eu escolho todos os produtos e depois clico no botão escolher)... Por exemplo: Eu digito guaraná, escolho 2... Digito coca, escolho 2... Ai quando eu clicar em escolher ele deveria colocar todos esses 4 produtos no array, porém ele não faz.. ele entende que o primeiro produto pesquisado não está escolhido.

Agora se eu digito guaraná, escolho 2... Digito coca, escolho 2.. *Apago o que está no campo pesquisa*.. Ele volta pro formulário completo e registra todos os produtos

Comment: Sim... mas quando vc faz a pesquisa no DB ela é feita aonde? Aonde está esse script? É em php ou javascript? Você poderia postar o script da pesquisa?

Comment: O session_start() está aonde?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o trecho do código onde inicializa a session e onde chama os arquivos javascript. A pesquisa é feita pelo componente DataTable.

Comment: Só um comentário sobre o HTML ali, com o `input type="number"` você não precisaria daqueles botões de incremento e decremento de quantidade, ele já tem esses botões ali.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Vou arrumar isso.

Answer (score 0):

Este [dataTable](http://datatables.net/) é meio enjoado mesmo, ele funciona desse modo mesmo, só envia o formulário do que está na tela. Para poder enviar outros campos, você precisa fazer um pouco de trabalho manual rs.

O que precisa ser feito é, ao submeter o formulário, buscar os campos de formulário que não estão sendo exibidos em tela e adicioná-los como `hidden` antes do envio, ou dentro de algum elemento igualmente invisível.

O código a seguir faz isso, procura nas linhas tudo que for um `input` que não está visível na dataTable e adiciona num `div` oculto. Também altere a parte da inclusão de bibliotecas para usar versões mais atualizadas, e adicionei ali no meio para usar o estilo do :

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jqu‌​ery.min.js"></script‌​>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabela_produtos').dataTable();

  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var seletor = 'input';
    var oForm = $(this);
    oForm.find('.dataTable').each(function () {
      var oTable = $(this).DataTable();
      var todos = $(oTable.rows().nodes()).find(seletor);
      var atual = $(oTable.rows({page:'current'}).nodes()).find(seletor);
      // adiciona os inputs que não estão visíveis ao form, escondendo eles
      var oDivOculto = $('<div>').attr('style', 'display: none');
      oDivOculto.append(todos.not(atual));
      oForm.append(oDivOculto);
    });
  });

} );
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém eu não sou muito conhecedor do JavaScript e não sei em qual parte do código esse trecho deve ser inserido. Tentei inserir logo no início da ação do PHP e no começo da página junto com as outras chamadas JavaScript, porém não funcionou. Qual é a maneira correta de implementar esse código?

Comment: Pode ser logo após o ser `$('#tabela_produtos').dataTable();`. Ali dentro do `$(document).ready`. O `$('form').on('submit', ...` será sempre executado quando submeter o formulário.

Comment: Coloquei aonde você disse e ele continua não pegando os produtos selecionados fora da listagem..

Comment: Editei o código para incluir o seu trecho de javascript, veja se está assim. Outra coisa, aparece algum erro no console do Chrome quando você submete o formulário? Caso não saiba onde fica, aperte F12, tem uma aba 'console', limpe qualquer erro que apareça primeiro, faça o submit e veja se deu algum erro. Outra coisa, você está com o dataTables atualizado? Pode ser isso também.

Comment: Eu baixei diretamente do site do dataTable (datatables.net/download/index). Logo quando a página é carregada, aparecem esses erros: 
pedido.php:89 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ pedido.php:89(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:19each @ jquery.min.js:12ready @ jquery.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:19 

E ao submeter o formulário: Uncaught TypeError $(...).on is not a pedido.php?acao=escolher_produto:89 function(...)

Comment: Reparei só agora, seu jquery está numa versão um bocado antiga... troque a linha de incluir o script para `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Aliás, o jQuery já está na versão 3.1. Um upgrade pode ser interessante, caso queira fazer leia [o guia de atualização do jQuery](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/)

Comment: Quando eu atualizo a linha que chama a Jquery, o DataTable para de funcionar... Não mostra mais o campo "pesquisa"..

Comment: Será que pegou a versão que não usa o jQuery por engano? Lá tem vários botões pra apertar e fica meio confuso. Atualizei a resposta com a parte HTML de inclusão dos scripts, troque e veja se agora vai...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu acabei solucionando o problema utilizando jquery e ajax. Ao clicar no botão mais ele insere a quantidade no array (e no html, consequentemente mostra o value atualizado do array) e ao clicar no botão menos ele deleta 1 da quantidade.